# spotify playlist limit 100

Tags: spotify, spotify-app

trying to list songs in a playlist using web API I get 108 songs (?). 
I see some 100 limit in the playlist.

```
debian:~/user$ curl -Ss -H "Authorization: Bearer atkn" https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/bugenwilla/playlists|jq -r '.items[]|select(.name=="myplaylist")|[.tracks.total, .id]'
[
  1543,
  "playlistid"
]

debian:~/user$ curl -Ss -H "Authorization: Bearer atkn" https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/username/playlists/playlistid/tracks | jq -r '.items[] | .track.album.artists[].name' | wc -l
108

debian:~/user$ curl -Ss -H "Authorization: Bearer atkn" https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/username/playlists/playlistid/tracks | jq -r '.limit, .total'
100
1543
```

1) why it shows 108 songs and not limit 100?
2) is there a way to change the limit / show all 1543 songs in the playlist?

Answer (score 0):

1. With that jq expression, you are counting 108 album artists, not tracks. There are probably a few tracks that are on an album that is made by more than one artist.
2. The documentation for the api method you call https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-playlists-tracks/ mentions a query parameter called `offset`. It defaults to 0. Setting it to 100, will give you the next hundred tracks. https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/username/playlists/playlistid/tracks?offset=100